# Convert LPSTR to BSTR using win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I see how to do this using MFC, but what is the best way to convert a LPSTR to a BSTR in C++ using only the win32 libraries.

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar + SysAllocString

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <comutil.h>

LPSTR myLpstr = "Hello World!";
_bstr_t bstr = _bstr_T(myLpstr);
```

It also needs library comsupp.lib

Comment: He said "only the win32 libraries".

Comment: "comsupp.lib" is for "COM support".  COM is part of Win32.

Comment: Agreed, but you should probably be using comsuppw.lib (which uses wchar_t* instead of unsigned short* in APIs). It's actually not a Win32 library (not in PSDK, no matching DLL) but a Visual C++ static library. So, you don't need to distribute MFC, but it's still not portable to MingW

Answer (score 2):

Use [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx).

Note that SysAllocString takes an `OLECHAR*` argument, which is effectively a `WCHAR*`, not a `CHAR*`. This shouldn't be a problem unless you're compiling without `UNICODE` defined--but don't do that.

Comment: Whether or not UNICODE is defined is not going to have any effect on an LPSTR.  You need to show how to convert the string.

Comment: -1, agree  with Hans Passant here. The Unicode define affects `LPTSTR`, not `LPWSTR` or `LPSTR`. Hence this answer is missing the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the concrete solution but I think this is gonna help you (especially part II):

[The Complete Guide to C++ Strings, Part I - Win32 Character Encodings](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide1.aspx)

[The Complete Guide to C++ Strings, Part II - String Wrapper Classes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide2.aspx)